# When to use subscript and when to make it a function?

Tags: notation

Let's say, I have a set of cats $C = \{ a, b, c, ... \}$. Each cat has a tail. I can say, that the lengths of the tails of cats are denoted as $t_a$, $t_b$, etc. Otherwise, I can say that they are denoted as $t(a)$, $t(b)$, etc. Which option is preferable and when?

Comment: I'd say whatever is more convenient for you.

Comment: In the case of discrete, non-numeric data, subscripts are fine. The functional notation would be appropriate in discourse explicitly related to set theory, IMO. But the nuance is thin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are valid, and the choice is based on personal preference and taste.  One benefit of the notation $t(a),\dots$ is that it allows you to refer to the function $t$ that maps from $C$ to lengths, which may be useful in some contexts.  One benefit of the notation $t_a,\dots$ is that if $C$ is finite and small, in some settings it might be intuitive to think of $t_a,t_b,\dots$ as separate variables (though of course the two are still equivalent).